# How to format C++ code in Visual Studio using my own rules?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-2019, code-formatting

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

1. I want to create a setting file for Visual Studio which consists of my own formatting rules and anyone can import those settings for their Visual Studio. (I think this is a simpler way for a newbie instead of instructing him to install a format code extension). I name this file `MyFormattingRules.vssettings`. Am I right about this file extension?
2. How to set the formatting rules in this file using my own rules?

   I found this link but it does not really do what I want.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/visualstudio/ide/cpp-editorconfig-properties?view=vs-2019

   For example:

- If a function has only 1 input parameter, then we write it in only one line, but if it has from 2 input parameters, then we write each parameter in one line

Example1.h

```
void myFunc(int param);

void myFunc2(
    int param1,
    int param2,
    int param3);
```

- When I declare a variable in a class, after saving my file, it will change the name of my variable.

Example2.h

```
class Myclass
{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    int myVar;
}
```

After saving, `myVar` should become `m_myVar`. Is this possible to do such things with the setting file? If not, can you suggest a tool that can do this?

3. After importing my setting file, how to do such that whenever I save my file (.cpp or .h), my formatting rules will be applied?

Can you give me an example of such a file?

Comment: clang-format would be an alternative (which is not IDE dependent).

Comment: clang-tidy has rules for naming, but I don't think IDE does those changes automatically, as it requires more manual checks than "simple" formtatting.

Comment: You can make a .clang-format file in the root of your solution. Visual studio will pick that up. Some info here : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/

Comment: You need to customize clang-format.exe and add it to VS. The default shortcut is ctrl+k+d.https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRCir.png